# using .Net Core 2.1 Implementing Castle.Core.Logging.ILoggerFactory interface

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, castle-windsor, nlog

I am trying to create log entry with NLog via IoC in my Controller action
By following https://davidsiew.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/castle-windsor-nlog-integration/ tutorial, I found out that I need to change a line in MyWindsorInstaller class.
Source for this tutorial: https://github.com/DavidSSL/CastleWindsorWithNlog?source=c

Instead of this:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog).WithConfig("NLog.config"));
```

I need to use THIS:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing<NLogLoggerFactory> ().WithConfig("NLog.config"));
```

Here  NLogLoggerFactory is class that Implements Castle.Core.Logging.**ILoggerFactory** interface, now I need to add the implementation. For now it looks like this:

```
using Castle.Core.Logging;

public class NLogLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
{
    private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    public ILogger Create(Type type)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ILogger Create(string name)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ILogger Create(Type type, LoggerLevel level)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ILogger Create(string name, LoggerLevel level)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

But why it has 4 different Create() methods? Surely that is because Interface has it. But I am not sure what is next. If I try to initialize Nlog logger, it woun't allow me because NLog is not of required return type. So I wonder maybe someone has any tips, or maybe examples of this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create your own `NLogLoggerFactory`. There's already one provided out of the box.

Just use `NLogFactory` from `Castle.Services.Logging.NLogIntegration` namespace.